# Publishing platform event in doInit of Aura or page load action cause any security vulnerability?

Tags: platform-event, security-review, security-scanner

We have a scenario to publish platform event in doInit of Aura Component (or) action of visualforce page, where in the platform event trigger we're making a dml.

As far as we researched and debugged, the platform event trigger is executing in different transaction. So i dont think it will cause **CSRF Vulnerability** issue.

So publishing platform event in doInit of LC or action of vf page cause any security vulnerability?

If so, this is the scenario which im trying to accomplish

1. On Button Click from LC, we're invoking a vf Page from apex and getting the vf page blob as getContentAsPdf

[image]
2. So In Vf Page Action, we're processing some soqls and constructing table for the end user, it has very big logic inside the vf page action and after the all table construction, we are updating status in respective record(either criteria met or not)
3. As long as we're doing DML in page action, caught under security review with **CSRF Vulnerability**

So what we're achieving here is to pass the status which calculated in vf page context, we tried with setting the status in static, get set variable, page reference get params. But none worked for us.

So after we faced all the issues, we came across platform event firing from vf page context handling that in trigger to make respective dml

Any best solution to overcome this? Any suggestions or thoughts are much appreciated.

Comment: It should not cause any Vulnerability since platform events runs completely in a separate context and are separate transactions.